# Suppose that $\sqrt{n}(X_n-X) \overset{D} \to \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. What does $(\sqrt{n}(X_n-X))^2$ converge in distribution to?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose that $\sqrt{n}(X_n-X) \overset{D} \to \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. I am curious what $(\sqrt{n}(X_n-X))^2 = n(X_n-X)$ converges in distribution to. I have tried to use the delta method, but it appears that it only works for functions applied within. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I think you can use the second order delta method here. See for example page 6 of http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/~hchen/teaching/StatInference/notes/lecture40.pdf

Comment: @Winther Not needed, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Y_n \overset{D} \to Y$, then $Y_n^2 \overset{D} \to Y^2$.  The square of a $\mathcal N(0, 1)$ random variable has a chi-square distribution with $1$ degree of freedom, and so the square of a $\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ is $\sigma^2$ times a chi-square random variable.

Comment: My impression was that in general, if $X_n \overset{D}\to X$ and $Y_n \overset{D}\to Y$, that it wasn't true that Slutsky's theorem gives $X_nY_n \overset{D}\to XY$. It seems we have the above with $Y_nY_n \overset{D}\to Y^2$. What result allows this?

Comment: For $z \ge 0$, $$\mathbb P(Y_n^2 \le z) = \mathbb P(-\sqrt{z} \le Y_n \le \sqrt{z}) \to \mathbb P(-\sqrt{z} \le Y \le \sqrt{z}) = \mathbb P(Y^2 \le z)$$ if the cdf of $Y^2$ is continuous at $z$ (which implies the cdf of $Y$ is continuous at $\pm \sqrt{z}$).

Comment: @user321627 Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem